# how to combine tables?

Tags: python, django

please help make the ability to dynamically select status.

I have a model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    CHOICES_status = (
        ('0', 'none'),
        ('1', 'status1'),
        ('2', 'status2'),
        ('3', 'status3'),
        ('4', 'status4'),
    )   

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    family = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    nation = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, choices=CHOICES_status, default='0')
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='userprofile/', blank=True)
    nation_show = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
```

it has a fixed set of statuses. creating a user selects a certain status.

I put a set of statuses in a separate table:

```
class UserStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Now I need to do so variable CHOICES_status generated dynamically based on the model UserStatus

Comment: Now you have gone too far down the garden path of using a choice array like this in Django, and created an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The answer is to use a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: how are you populating the UserStatus table? or who does it?

Comment: operator fills database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#models.py
class ProfileStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32)


class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    status = models.ForeignKey(ProfileStatus)


#forms.py
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    status = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ProfileStatus.objects.all())
```